# ¿Por qué está mal el desarrollo de esta función con operador ternario?

Tags: javascript, operador-ternario

```
function numeroPositivo(numero) {
    //modificar debajo de esta línea
 
    return (numero > 0) 
  ? "Es positivo" 
    : "Es negativo" 
      ? numero === 0
        : false;
}
```

La función recibe un entero y tengo que devolver un `string` que diga si es positivo, negativo y si es cero devolver `false`

Quiero saber por qué está mal este operador ternario y cómo puedo hacerlo bien, no llego a entender como anidarlos, sé cómo hacerlo con `if else`, pero quiero aprender esta forma

Answer (score 8):

Tu error está en el segundo operador ternario, ya que ya finalizaste el primero y no se puede acceder a un segundo después del `return`

Te propongo usar este operador

```
numero === 0 ? false : numero > 0 ? "Es positivo" : "Es negativo"
```

Comprobando primero si el número es `0` y devolver `false`, si no es `0`, accedemos al segundo operador que determinará si el número es positivo o negativo

```js
function numeroPositivo(n) {
  return n === 0 ? false : n > 0 ? "Es positivo" : "Es negativo";
}

console.log(numeroPositivo(1)); // Es positivo
console.log(numeroPositivo(0)); // false
console.log(numeroPositivo(-1)); // Es negativo
```

Answer (score 4):

El uso del operador tornaría evalúa si el valor es `true` o `false`  si es `true` devolverá el primer valor de lo contrario el segundo

```
let valor = false
let resultado = valor ? "Es true" : "es false"
```

Esto devolverá `"es false"`  . También puedes hacer operaciones múltiples

```
var firstCheck = false,
   secondCheck = false,
   access = firstCheck ? "Acceso Denegado" : secondCheck ? "Acceso Denegado" : "Acceso Permitido";

console.log( access ); // muestra "Acceso Permitido"
```

Puedes leer más en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que tu función queda incompleta con todas las soluciones propuestas, porque reconocerá como `negativo` valores que en realidad no son válidos.

En caso de que se requiera diferenciar aquellos valores que no entran dentro del rango: igual, mayor o menor que cero, podrías hacer algo así para devolver `Invalid` u otra cosa.

```js
function checkValue(n){
    return n===0 ? false
         : n>0 ? '+'
         : n<0 ? '-'
         : 'Invalid';
}



console.log(checkValue(1));         // +
console.log(checkValue(0));         // false
console.log(checkValue(-1));        // -
console.log(checkValue('a'));       // Invalid
console.log(checkValue(null));      // Invalid
console.log(checkValue([0,1]));     // Invalid
console.log(checkValue({'a':1}));   // Invalid
console.log(checkValue(undefined)); // Invalid
console.log(checkValue(NaN));       // Invalid
```

Answer (score 3):

"numero===0" también es una "pregunta", así que el '?' va después, no antes.

```js
function numeroPositivo(numero) {
  return numero > 0 ? // Pregunta
    "Es positivo" // Respuesta en caso afirmativo
    : numero === 0 ? // Respuesta en caso negativo, hace otra pregunta...
    false // Respuesta en caso afirmativo (2ª pregunta)
    : "Es negativo"; // Respuesta en caso negativo (2ª pregunta)
}
console.log(numeroPositivo(2));
console.log(numeroPositivo(-2));
console.log(numeroPositivo(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Como dijo el compa#ero es que estas intentando usar un segundo ternario antes de retornar el primero, es decir, tras los dos ternarios. Puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const positiveNumber = (n) => {
  return n === 0 ?
    false
  :
    n > 0 ?
      'Es positivo'
    :
      'No es positivo'
}
```

Comment: *no puedes ejecutar dos operaciones ternarias dentro de una misma*-> Puedes encadenar tantos ternarios como te apetezca, y sin necesidad de paréntesis... el problema que tiene es que está intentando poner un segundo operador ternario tras el *return* del primero, es decir, tras los dos valores. Para encadenar ternarios es necesario pasarlos como uno de los dos valores (tal como haces en tu ejemplo). Pero por poder, puedes poner cuantos quieras, y si los escribes en múltiples líneas son bastante sencillos de leer / seguir, incluso sin paréntesis.

Comment: Claro... tienes razon, actualizare mi explicacion por que lo que esta mal es la formulacion de la respuesta